# How to set time_zone for Source DB in AWS DMS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, dms

I am trying to migrate a MySQL database to Aurora, but can't get the timezone set.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.ConnectionAttributes.html#CHAP_Introduction.ConnectionAttributes.MySQL): "Valid values are the standard time zone abbreviations for the operating system hosting the source MySQL database."

Executing *date* on my Linux (Ubuntu) machine shows: `Thu Dec  7 10:27:48 AEDT 2017`.

I have configured the Source Endpoint to use:

**Extra connection attributes**: *initstmt=SET time_zone=AEDT*

Which results in my connection test to fail with:

```
Error Details: [errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=1022502, errMessage=Cannot connect to ODBC provider ODBC general error., errDetails= RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: HY000 NativeError: 1298 Message: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'AEDT' ODBC general error.]
```

I've tried `"Australia/Sydney"` as well (same value as in RDS Parameter Groups) but getting the same error.

Any ideas?

*I am totally aware of that this should be UTC. Not my choice - legacy.*

**Update: It seems `initstmt=SET time_zone="+11:00"` works, but leading to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687470/timezone-awareness-differences-between-system-tz-and-db-tz) issue.**

Comment: Don't quote the time zone identifier: `initstmt=SET time_zone=AEDT`

Comment: Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Use a dash: `initstmt=SET time-zone=AEDT`

Comment: Doesn't work either. Fails with recognizing parameter "time".

Comment: Use UTC offset: `initstmt=SET time_zone=UTC+11`

Comment: Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'UTC+11'

Comment: What OS hosts the source database?

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu14)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160663/discussion-between-bishop-and-kev).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Migrate MySQL from a Linux server to Aurora, the user replication instead of DMS. DMS will not support many DDL during the data load. So create a replication between MySQL to Aurora.

Master - Your current MySQL.
slave - Aurora.

## Prepare:

- Both instances are able to communicate with each other.
- The master must be 5.5 or greater version.
- binlog_format to ROW on the Master MySQL.

## Create user for replication:

```
CREATE USER 'rep_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'rep_user';  
GRANT REPLICATION slave ON *.* TO 'rep_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'rep_user';  
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## Take dump with Binlog details:

```
mysqldump -u user -p dbname --master-data=2 > backup.sql
```

`less backup.sql`
this will give you the binlog file name and its position.

## Restore the Backup:

```
mysql -h auroraendpoint -u user -p dbname < backup.sql
```

## Enable replication:

```
CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('Master_RDS_EndPoint', 3306,    'Replication_user_name', 'Replication_User_password', 'BinLog_FileName', BingLog_Position, 0);
```

## Strat replication:

```
call mysql.rds_start_replication;
```

## Cutover:

During the maintenance window do a cutover and make the Aurora as a master.

```
call mysql.rds_stop_replication;  
CALL mysql.rds_reset_external_master;
```