# Timezone awareness differences between System TZ and DB TZ?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, utc, rds, amazon-aurora

I am currently migrating a database from a local MySQL host to Aurora in RDS.

Checking the time zone settings on both systems using:

```
SELECT @@system_time_zone, @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone, NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP();
```

**Local Mysql**

```
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| @@system_time_zone | @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone | NOW()               | UTC_TIMESTAMP()     |
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| AEDT               | SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              | 2017-12-07 15:05:29 | 2017-12-07 04:05:29 |
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**RDS (Aurora)**

```
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| @@system_time_zone | @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone | NOW()               | UTC_TIMESTAMP()     |
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| UTC                | Australia/Sydney   | Australia/Sydney    | 2017-12-07 15:05:29 | 2017-12-07 04:05:29 |
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Issue:**

The timestamps after 1st October (that's when DST happens) are equal, but differ by one hour before, see below:

**Local MySQL**

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id     | created_at          | updated_at          |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      1 | 2017-08-21 05:08:02 | 2017-08-21 05:20:01 |
|      2 | 2017-08-21 05:08:02 | 2017-08-21 05:20:01 |
|      3 | 2017-08-21 05:08:02 | 2017-08-21 05:20:01 |
|  30000 | 2017-09-07 00:45:02 | 2017-09-07 01:10:03 |
|  98350 | 2017-09-30 19:15:03 | 2017-09-30 19:40:03 |
|  98357 | 2017-10-01 08:00:02 | 2017-10-01 08:25:03 |
|  98358 | 2017-10-01 08:00:02 | 2017-10-01 08:25:03 |
|  98359 | 2017-10-01 08:00:02 | 2017-10-01 08:25:03 |
| 100361 | 2017-10-01 19:05:03 | 2017-10-01 19:30:03 |
| 100411 | 2017-10-01 19:10:04 | 2017-10-01 19:35:03 |
| 100412 | 2017-10-01 19:10:04 | 2017-10-01 19:35:03 |
| 394449 | 2017-12-07 08:30:03 | 2017-12-07 09:00:04 |
| 394472 | 2017-12-07 08:30:03 | 2017-12-07 09:00:08 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**RDS (Aurora)**

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id     | created_at          | updated_at          |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      1 | 2017-08-21 06:08:02 | 2017-08-21 06:20:01 |
|      2 | 2017-08-21 06:08:02 | 2017-08-21 06:20:01 |
|      3 | 2017-08-21 06:08:02 | 2017-08-21 06:20:01 |
|  30000 | 2017-09-07 01:45:02 | 2017-09-07 02:10:03 |
|  98350 | 2017-09-30 20:15:03 | 2017-09-30 20:40:03 |
|  98357 | 2017-10-01 08:00:02 | 2017-10-01 08:25:03 |
|  98358 | 2017-10-01 08:00:02 | 2017-10-01 08:25:03 |
|  98359 | 2017-10-01 08:00:02 | 2017-10-01 08:25:03 |
| 100361 | 2017-10-01 19:05:03 | 2017-10-01 19:30:03 |
| 100411 | 2017-10-01 19:10:04 | 2017-10-01 19:35:03 |
| 100412 | 2017-10-01 19:10:04 | 2017-10-01 19:35:03 |
| 394449 | 2017-12-07 08:30:03 | 2017-12-07 09:00:04 |
| 394472 | 2017-12-07 08:30:03 | 2017-12-07 09:00:08 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Questions:**

1. Are both settings timezone aware?
2. If not, which is not?
3. How can I tell it to be? :-)
4. Afaik MySQL stores timestamps in UTC and converts them transparently upon read and write based on the timezone (see this [SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650910/1252307) for more information). Is there any way to get the raw value of a timestamp field without *any* (transparent or non transparent) conversions?

Comment: If that upvote was not accidentally, it was the quickest I've ever received ^^